# Let $f : x \in \mathbb{R} \rightarrow -x^{4}-2x^{3}+7x$ . Where is it concave?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

So I have the following function $f : x \in \mathbb{R} \rightarrow -x^{4}-2x^{3}+7x$ and I have $A$={$\alpha \in \mathbb{R} : $f is concave in $(-\infty,\alpha)$}. I have following alternatives and I have to find which one is correct:

> a) $\ supA=1$

> b) $\ infA=1$

> c) $\ infA=-1$

> d) $\ supA= -1$

I thought about it so that I have to find where the second derivative is less than 0, and solving $-12x^{2}-12x <0$ and got $x>-1$ and $x<0$ so I thought that $0$ would be the supremum of A and $-1$ its Infimum.

I would be really thankful for a little bit of help,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It should be $x>0$ or $x<-1$, which gives the answer $d$.

Actually.

$f$ concave on $(-\infty,-1]$ and $f$ concave on $[0,+\infty).$